# I have a job offer for a later joining date. What happens if my company gets acquired before I join?

Tags: job-offer, acquisition

I am currently a student. I got a job offer, with joining date after few months. I am still few months away from joining and cannot join sooner because I am in school. There are news rumors of this company possibly getting acquired. I'm not sure if the job offer and the benefits, like bonus, stock, etc. will still hold after that.

Comment: Something similar happened to me - the acquisition had already happened when I got the offer, but the company was still essentially operating as an independent company. When the full HR integration happened, yes, lots of benefits changed, but it was a year and a half after the official acquisition, and after I had started. At that point my change in benefits was the same as every other employee.

Comment: I'd just ask HR what would happen to your job offer if the acquisition went through. If it's on the news it's not rude to ask about.

Comment: @inferno Please add the relevant country tag (and US state if that applies). Employment law differs from place to place.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some recommendations:

- Get the offer in writing if possible.
- Maintain an active relationship with the company, your future manager, any interviewers you met/future teammates, and someone in HR there. Make sure you are in the front of their mind.
- Ask your contacts about possible acquisitions you read about in the news. Don't pester them but phrase it as excitement and curiosity.
- Depending on what you learn, keep looking around for other companies to interview with.
- 2-3 weeks before you would start work, ramp up all this activity, so you can have confidence in their offer, or your ability to get another offer elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens if my company gets acquired before I join?

When a company is acquired, all bets are off. The acquiring company may or may not honor your job offer.

I've been in companies that were acquired. In each case, all reqs were frozen until they could be reviewed at a later date.

And every time I've been involved in a acquisition (either as acquirer or acquired), at least some people lost their jobs. That's just the way it goes.

Now often an acquiring company will just let things proceed as before for a while, and that would mean your offer still exists. But you'll just need to wait to find out for sure.